# Copy and paste VBA code - I want to use across multiple sheets

Tags: vba, copy, paste

I'm very new to VBA.  I have some code that will copy data that meets a certain criteria in one sheet to another master sheet.  I have multiple other worksheets that I want to copy from into the master.  How do I amend my code to do that please?

Thanks in advance.

```
Sub copyPaste()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wt As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("S_Q")
    Set wt = Sheets("master")
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim lr As Integer
    lr = ws.Range("y" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim lt As Long

    For i = 1 To lr
    lt = wt.Range("y" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If ws.Range("bz" & i) > 14 Then
        ws.Range("y" & i).EntireRow.Copy wt.Range("a" & lt + 1)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying the filter on various columns and it working on some and not others; with no apparent reasoning.  I decided to rejig the spreadsheets and put the column to be filtered in the first column.  This seems to be working so far.

Answer (score 0):

Without diving too far into the specifics of your code itself - will the criteria be the same for all worksheets you're wanting to run it on? And is the layout of the data in all of those worksheets?

If so, and if your current code is doing what you need it to do for Worksheet A and we just need to expand that to also handle Worksheets B through X, then you could get rid of your dim/set ws lines, and instead change your first line to

```
sub copyPaste(ws as worksheet)
```

This would allow you to then use a separate procedure to call this procedure for each of your worksheets that it needs to be run on. Below is an example using the worksheet from your original code:

```
call copyPaste(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("S_Q"))
```

Comment: Thanks McMookerson.  Yes the criteria and data layout is the same I just need it to run across multiple sheets and paste all of the data that meets the criteria from sheet a-z into the master sheet.  As I said I'm very new to VBA.  I've change my code to put that in the first line and deleted out the WS lines but it now won't let me run it.

Comment: Are you receiving any specific errors after that change? Can you post what your code looks like now so that we can dig deeper?

Comment: Sub Copy_Filtered_WkShts()
       
    Sheets("master").Unprotect Password:="password"
    Sheets("A_G").Unprotect Password:="password"
    Sheets("F_P").Unprotect Password:="password"
    Sheets("CC").Unprotect Password:="password"
   
     Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim writeRow As Long
    
Sheets("master").UsedRange.Offset(1).ClearContents
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If (ws.Name <> "master") Then
              writeRow = Sheets("master").Cells(Rows.count, "y").End(xlUp).Row + 1

Comment: With ws
               .AutoFilterMode = False
           With .UsedRange
       .AutoFilter Field:=78, Criteria1:=">14", _
       Operator:=xlAnd
        .Offset(1).Copy Destination:=Sheets("master").Range("A" & writeRow)
            End With
            .AutoFilterMode = False
        End With    End If
Next ws
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Sheets("master").Protect Password:="password"
Sheets("A_G").Protect Password:="password"
Sheets("F_P").Protect Password:="password"
Sheets("CC").Protect Password:="password"
End Sub

Comment: Sorry had to split across 2 comments and it keeps losing the formatting.  Sorry for the delay in getting back to you McMookerson.

Answer (score 0):

I would put the sheets of interest to loop over in an array and loop that. I would also use Union to gather the qualifying ranges and paste in one go to be more efficient.

I would also use a helper function to retrieve the last row and add one to that to get next row.

Also, use `Long` rather than `Integer` to avoid potential overflow as there are more rows in a sheet than Integer can handle.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub copyPaste()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wt As Worksheet, sheetsOfInterest(), unionRng As Range
    Dim i As Long, lastRow As Long, lastRowMaster As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    sheetsOfInterest = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "S_Q")

    Set wt = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("master")

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetsOfInterest)

        lastRow = GetLastRow(ws, 25)

        For i = 1 To lastRow

            If ws.Range("BZ" & i) > 14 Then
                If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then
                    Set unionRng = Union(unionRng, ws.Range("bz" & i))
                Else
                    Set unionRng = ws.Range("BZ" & i)
                End If
            End If
        Next i
        If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then
            With wt
                unionRng.EntireRow.Copy .Range("A" & GetLastRow(wt, 1) + 1)
            End With
        End If
        Set unionRng = Nothing
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Public Function GetLastRow(ByVal ws As Worksheet, Optional ByVal columnNumber As Long = 1) As Long
    With ws
        GetLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, columnNumber).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Did you try this please?